# Amqplib no ack messages bug

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using C-compilled library for rabbit AMQP.
Trying to get messages from queue without acknowledge I get only top 3 messages on consume callback.
Server monitoring shows that 3 messages was gotten without acknowledge.

If I use php-amqplib I got all messages from queue without acknowledge while session.

Code like:

```
$cnn = new AMQPConnection();
$cnn->setLogin('guest');
$cnn->setPassword('guest');

if ($cnn->connect()) {
} else {
    die("Error");
}

$channel = new AMQPChannel($cnn);
$exchange = new AMQPExchange($channel);
$exchange->setName('test');
$exchange->setType(AMQP_EX_TYPE_TOPIC);
$exchange->setFlags(AMQP_DURABLE | AMQP_AUTODELETE | AMQP_PASSIVE);

try {
    $exchange->declareExchange();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
    die(0);
}

$q = new AMQPQueue($channel);
$q->setName('queue');
$q->setFlags(AMQP_DURABLE | AMQP_PASSIVE);
$cnt = $q->declareQueue();

$q->bind($exchange->getName(),'token');

$cb = function(AMQPEnvelope $params, AMQPQueue $queue) {
    print_r($params->getBody());
    echo "\n";
};

while (true) {
    $q->consume($cb);
}

$cnn->disconnect();
```

Comment: Have you tried `AMQP_AUTOACK`?

Comment: It will ACK all messages in queue. But I want to read all of them without acknowledge